# don't want to close popup on click of hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

I have child window which has a hyperlink. On click of hyperlink i have to redirect to parent window. I could do this using following syntax

```
<h:outputLink id="detail" onclick="javascript:redirectToCase(#{id})" >
   <f:param id="id" name="id" value="#{refId}"/>
   <h:outputText id="textId" value="#{refId}"/>
</h:outputLink>

function redirectToCase(id){
    window.opener.location.href="/myapp/faces/abc/xyz.jsp?caseId="+id;
}
```

When i click on hyperlink it closes the child popup and redirects to main page. I don't want to close the child popup. How can i do this ?

Comment: What part of this isn't working?

Comment: This wouldn't close the popup. Do you mean it loses focus and main window is brought in front?

Comment: It doesn't lose the focus rather it closes popup. I'm using JSF outputLink. i've given some more detail in question

Comment: what browser are using to test? it worked in my test

Comment: I'm guessing it's that JSF is doing something funky there. Can you post the actual rendered HTML for the link that is created? (the `<a>` tag when you hit view source)

Comment: @Pankaj if yu can test in chrome or firefox... as we never know what happens with IE8 lol

Comment: @Joe, here is the code <a href="?id=24021" onmouseup="redirectToCase(24021);">24021</a>

Comment: One thing - your code doesn't match - you say `redirectToCase`, but the function in your question says `redirectToMainPage` - assuming that's just a typo...The tag that's built does both a redirect of the popup itself, and a javascript action to redirect the parent, but would not close the current window. Perhaps the response that comes back on the popup tells it to close itself. I'd recommend using Fiddler or browser dev tools to inspect the response that comes back on the popup - I'd bet it has a `self.close()` or something like that in the new response, which closes the popup.

Comment: @Joe, Thanks alot. I guess, you're right. While debugging, i could see a window.close function getting called in existing code on 'onbeforeunload' which is desired functionality for all other popup except in this case. Now i will have to prevent it, do you have any idea if there is any way to prevent this ?

Comment: Don't know - that event is kind of weird, so I don't know if there's any way to deal with it.